# Repair-ServiceFabricPartition command

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

The Repair-ServiceFabricPartition command is used to forcefully bring a partition out of quorum loss. What exactly does the command do in order to accomplish this?

If I have a partition with a primary replica and two secondary replicas and the partition is storing a bunch of state. The secondary replicas have a copy of all of this state, obviously. If the two secondary replicas go down for some reason then my partition is in quorum loss and it will not perform writes. If I use this command to repair the partition and bring it out of quorum loss, what does this do?

Does Service Fabric spin up two entirely new replicas and then replicate the state to them? I assume if this is the case then it's not going to come out of quorum loss until both replicas have spun up and all of the state in that partition has been replicated to at least one of the secondaries?

Answer (score 0):

If replicas cannot come back up, you can run the cmdlet to bring the partition out of quorum loss.

No, the Service Fabric does not spin up new replicas. It in fact repairs the partition.

```
  PS C:\> Repair-ServiceFabricPartition -All
```

**This command repairs all the partitions that are in the quorum loss state.**

Comment: Need more information than this. How does it repair it? What if the replicas were on nodes that aren't coming back up?